# Static header scrolling body with long header

Tags: css, scroll

here's a little demonstration of what I did so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/pawLs132/3/

```
fictive "code" required to post this question
```

Basically I want a static header which is longer than the viewpoint but I want the text to be fit inside the set width so that when you scroll to the right the other part of the text will be displayed. (in this example meaning that I want the part "This should always be visible and when you s" to be initially visible and you have to scroll to the right to see the other part of the header)
I would also like it so that when you scroll the body there's no part of the body text visible inside the header container like it is now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will not be able to accomplish this with just CSS. You will need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed width with `position:fixed` on header

```
.on-top {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 305px;
    background: white;
}
```

Make sure the body has margin top to prevent overlap

```
.inner {
    margin-top: 3em;
}
```

Comment: But now the header and the body have a different scroll bar, I would like for them to share the same one.

Comment: Try it again, I've updated it. `position:sticky` instead of `fixed`.